# PhantomJS in TFS

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, phantomjs

We are trying to run Selenium Tests as part of our release with TFS Release Management with PhantomJS (Headless browser).

The tests runs smooth locally (of course =)) but when I try to run them on VSTF the test cant find any element.

I think that something is blocking the driver from starting, If I run the test locally with PhantomJs i get the Windows Security Alert.

[image]

Could it be that this is blocking in VSTF?
and in that case, is it possible to send an option when setting browserType?

```
 switch (settings.BrowserType)
            {
                case BrowserType.InternetExplorer:
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("Missing path!!");
                    break;
                case BrowserType.FireFox:
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                case BrowserType.Chrome:
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(settings.ChromeDriverPath);
                    break;
                case BrowserType.PhantomJS:
                    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(settings.PhantomDriverPath);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: What's detail error of the test when your run them on vstf?

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily  turn off firewall for troubleshooting to see if the test could be run successfully on the server.

And there has been a wonderful blog shows how to [running Selenium Tests as part of your release with VSTS Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2016/02/23/running-selenium-tests-as-part-of-your-release-with-vsts-release-management/). You could double check your build and release definition settings to narrow down the issue.